# Cannot parse JSON: No JsonObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  The problem is that the I cannot parse some JSON code because it has no JsonObject.  I'm pretty new to programming, and thus have no experience with JSON.  Forgive me if this is a newb question.  Here is my JSON code:

```
{
"item_id": "51c3d78797c3e6d8d3b546cf",
"item_name": "Cola, Cherry",
"brand_id": "51db3801176fe9790a89ae0b",
"brand_name": "Coke",
"item_description": "Cherry",
"updated_at": "2013-07-09T00:00:46.000Z",
"nf_ingredient_statement": "Carbonated Water, High Fructose Corn Syrup and/or Sucrose, Caramel Color, Phosphoric Acid, Natural Flavors, Caffeine.",
"nf_calories": 100,
"nf_calories_from_fat": 0,
"nf_total_fat": 0,
"nf_saturated_fat": null,
"nf_cholesterol": null,
"nf_sodium": 25,
"nf_total_carbohydrate": 28,
"nf_dietary_fiber": null,
"nf_sugars": 28,
"nf_protein": 0,
"nf_vitamin_a_dv": 0,
"nf_vitamin_c_dv": 0,
"nf_calcium_dv": 0,
"nf_iron_dv": 0,
"nf_servings_per_container": 6,
"nf_serving_size_qty": 8,
"nf_serving_size_unit": "fl oz",
}
```

Here's my code in my Android app.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    EditText one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    setContentView(R.layout.dbfiller);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String message = intent.getStringExtra("bnum");

    DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?upc="+message
            +"&appId=926eed28&appKey=d1366b0005a0d8f6898ff3df44b52867");
    // Depends on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        JSONObject json= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
        JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("");
        String test = (String) json2.get("nf_ingredient_statement");
        one.setText(test);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
}
```

I think the problem is here:

```
            JSONObject json= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
        JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("");
        String test = (String) json2.get("nf_ingredient_statement");
        one.setText(test);
```

But I don't know what I did wrong.  I've been banging my head on the wall for a while.  Here's my Logcat:

```
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748): org.json.JSONException: No value for 
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:574)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at com.example.foodsaver2.DatabaseFiller.onCreate(DatabaseFiller.java:57)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native     Method)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-29 12:36:13.636: W/System.err(25748):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The app doesn't crash because the json parser is located inside a try-catch method.  What's wrong here?  I've checked Google and SO, but I can't seem to find the solution.  Any help regarding this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string has a trailing comma at the end. Chop that off and it will likely fix your problem, as the code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the JSON code is off of a website.  How do I fix this problem then?

Comment: If you're getting the erroneous JSON from a different source, you'll need to create your own method to parse the input from it and make sure that each time something comes through, there's no trailing comma at the end.  That's just some basic string manipulation to validate input before trying to parse it as JSON.

Comment: You can ask the people that give you the service to fix their code :-)

Comment: @Nico Thanks for the response.  I will contact them now.

Comment: @EricWich Thanks, I will manipulate it and see what comes out.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your JSON. Remove the comma at the end of this line and try again:

```
"nf_serving_size_unit": "fl oz",
}
```

You can always check to see if your JSON is valid using the JSON validator at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the JSON code is off of a website. How do I fix this problem then?

Answer (score 0):

its a little stupid but give it a shot :)

```
    String finalResult;
    finalResult= result.substring(0, result.length() -2) + "}";
    Log.i("finalResult", finalResult);
```